# No more than 3 options in CheckedListBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, checkedlistbox

I use Visual Studio 2017 and i have a CheckedListBox that used to only have 2 options, and that worked like a charm. It now needs 4 options, but when i add the two other options, i cant choose anything of the 4.

I tested and tried the following:

- No ÆØÅ in the text (I have a word that uses Å, but tried without)
- Columnwidth set to much more than before
- Only 3 options (Which work)
- Creating a new CheckedListBox, with the same options (same error)
- Using different words than my options
- Removing all code behind the CheckedListBox

There does not come any errors, faults or anything. No errors in the code either.

The CheckedListBox:

```
        'CheckedListBox2
    '
    Me.CheckedListBox2.CheckOnClick = True
    Me.CheckedListBox2.ColumnWidth = 85
    Me.CheckedListBox2.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.CheckedListBox2.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Horsens", "Hedensted", "Odense", "Århus"})
    Me.CheckedListBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(198, 12)
    Me.CheckedListBox2.MultiColumn = True
    Me.CheckedListBox2.Name = "CheckedListBox2"
    Me.CheckedListBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(318, 19)
    Me.CheckedListBox2.TabIndex = 55
```

Comment: how you add or load this options?

Comment: @MarcoSadowski I simply add them in the designer. Click the CheckedListBox, and then on the small arrow that appears. In there i add the options with new lines for every option. It should be noted that i have other CheckedListBoxes that have 5 options, and work fine.

Comment: You are doing it wrong, but left no bread crumbs that could provide an explanation.  The design-time generated code is hidden in vb.net, click the Show All Files toolbar button in the Solution Explorer window.  Now you can see and open the Designer.vb file for the form.  And paste the relevant code from the InitializeComponent() method into your question.

Comment: @HansPassant I have added the code to the question. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes.  Looks like you've made it far too small with a height of only 19 pixels.  Not even enough to display the scrollbar that is needed to scroll to all items.  Make it bigger to get ahead, don't favor Multicolumn when you don't need it.

Comment: Pefect, without Multicolumn it works. But the reason behind Multicolumn, is that i want a thin but wide checkbox, which i dont know how do without Multicolumn. It also snaps to 19 pixels, so nothing i can do there.